# Look for files in a directory, scan other directory files and replace all filename occurence

Tags: javascript, linux, bash, replace, gruntjs

I'm looking to achieve a task with following requirements.

1. Scan files in dir1 directory
2. Look at the files (contents of file) under dir2 directory and replace all the filename occurrences found in step1 to say

Example:

Say I've directories css and js and lots of css files in css directory and similarly js files in js directory. I'd like to scan all jsp's in jsp directory for the occurrence of the css/js files and replace/append filenames a version param.

ie.. say i have css/example.css,    js/example.js and  jsp/example.jsp
and if exmaple.jsp contains :

```
<link rel = "stylesheet"...href = "example1.css"/>
```

Now I'd want

```
<link rel = "stylesheet"...href = "example1.css?version=1"/>
```

Ideal scenario is to replace all the occurrences of all files under css or js directory in the jsp files.

I'm exploring if any grunt tasks to achieve this or use any script with combination of some linux commands.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you or not.
first look at the css-dir. and each time i variable will be the file name in that directory.
now look at jsp-dir, and file the file that contains the i variable.
save that file name in var1
now append that name to the name of your file in css-dir

```
for i in `ls css-dir`
do
    var1=`ls jsp-dir | grep $i`
     mv $i "$i.$var1"
done
```